# PHP:Godaddy file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed"

Tags: php

Since this morning I was able to do the line below and now only the one with the www.google.com will work I tried with others site www.ebay.com www.yahoo.com even www.godaddy.com and got the same error

I called GoDaddy support and they say they have no issue

this is the entire code

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com');   //this doesn't work i get "failed to open stream: Connection timed"  only works with google.com
```

This is the full error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.yahoo.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/content/d/i/l/dilosolid/html/ebay/TextPHPXmlFileLoad.php on line 2
```

Comment: Do you have a command shell? Step 1: Use dig to check that you're getting valid DNS resolution for those domain names. Step 2: Use telnet to check that you can connect to port 80 on those IPs. In any case, I wouldn't at all be surprised that you're being blocked by GoDaddy, they're rather strict about what connections they allow.

Comment: if i use $feed = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); works fine but not with any other site and yes i can enter the domain by URL

Comment: What happens if you try `$feed = file_get_contents('https://www.yahoo.com/robots.txt');`